# Knowing a column of indexes how to get column of their values in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, insert

I have a DataFrame`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100, 100, 100).reshape(10, -1), columns=list(range(10)), index=list('abcdefghij'))` and I found some indexes using method `.idxmin(axis=1)` and getting Series`df_ind =`

- a 5
- b 8
- c 2
- d    0
- e    7
- f    0
- g    4
- h    6
- i    5
- j    2

How to get column of their values and than add (insert) it to df?

`df.insert(11, "values", df[df_ind])` gives me a 10x10 DataFrame, but not 1x10 DataFrame

Comment: what exactly is `df_ind`? A DataFrame? What are the headers? What is the exact expected output?

Comment: df_ind is a Series

Comment: Use `idx, cols = pd.factorize(df_ind)` `df['values'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]`

Comment: I see, then it's a modified indexing lookup (you need to reindex to ensure having the correct value in case the indexer is not aligned)

Comment: Are same indices in `df_ind` and `df`  in same order like in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to slice the values, you can use a modified [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
# first reindex the indexer to ensure
# having the correct final order
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df_ind.reindex(df.index))

# then perform indexing lookup
df['values'] = df.reindex(columns=cols).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  values
a  72 -53  17  92 -33  95   3 -91 -79 -64      95
b -13 -30 -12  40 -42  93 -61 -13  74 -12      74
c -19  65 -75 -23 -28 -91  48  15  97 -21     -75
d  75  92 -18  -1  77 -71  47  47  42  67      75
e -68  93 -91  85  27 -68 -69  51  63  14      51
f  83 -72 -66  28  28  64 -47  33 -62 -83      83
g -21  32   5 -58  86 -69  20 -99 -35  69      86
h -43 -65   2  19 -89  74 -18  -9  28  42     -18
i  -1 -47  40  21  70 -16 -32 -94  96 -53     -16
j  27  31   0  80 -22  43  48  86 -77  41       0
```

Output if the original DataFrame was in a different order:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  values
c -19  65 -75 -23 -28 -91  48  15  97 -21     -75
e -68  93 -91  85  27 -68 -69  51  63  14      51
h -43 -65   2  19 -89  74 -18  -9  28  42     -18
d  75  92 -18  -1  77 -71  47  47  42  67      75
g -21  32   5 -58  86 -69  20 -99 -35  69      86
i  -1 -47  40  21  70 -16 -32 -94  96 -53     -16
b -13 -30 -12  40 -42  93 -61 -13  74 -12      74
a  72 -53  17  92 -33  95   3 -91 -79 -64      95
j  27  31   0  80 -22  43  48  86 -77  41       0
f  83 -72 -66  28  28  64 -47  33 -62 -83      83
```

Reproducible `df_ind`:

```
df_ind = pd.Series({'a': 5, 'b': 8, 'c': 2, 'd': 0, 'e': 7, 'f': 0, 'g': 4, 'h': 6, 'i': 5, 'j': 2})
```